# Python function with default argument inside loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for i in range(5):
   def test(i=i):
      print(i)

test()
test()
test()
test()
test()
```

This prints 4 every time? Can someone help me understanding this.

Comment: You defined the function `test` five times. After you were done defining it five times, you were left with the last one you made, which is when `i==4`.

Comment: I expanded the for and added some comments.

Comment: If you want to create several functions like this, put them in a list or a dict.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You redefine the `test` 4 times:

same as:

```
#define test
def test(i = 0):
    print(i)

#redefine test
def test(i = 1):
    print(i)

#redefine test
def test(i = 2):
    print(i)

#redefine test
def test(i = 3):
    print(i)

#redefine test
def test(i = 4):
    print(i)
```

so you have only 1 `test()` the last one.

Answer (score 3):

The function `test` is redefined every iteration of the loop.

By the time the loop is done, `test` is simply:

```
def test(i=4):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

first your script completes for loop, by the end of for loop, i value is 4

Then how many ever times, you can call `test()`, it will print 4

I have added few prints to your code, so that you can understand the flow better

```
for i in range(5):
   print(i)
   def test(i=i):
      print("test")
      print(i)

test()
test()
test()
test()
test()
```

Output will be:

```
0
1
2
3
4
test
4
test
4
test
4
test
4
test
4
```